# Disable the button after the click, and change it's value

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, button

I have a Laravel project, where I allow people to subscribe to specific campaigns. There is a button "Subscribe", and once pressed, I write the information in the pivot table.

The relation between User and Campaign is belongsToMany both ways.

The question is, how could I disable such button, so client's couldn't subscribe to the same campaign many times? In my thoughts, after the button click, it would get disabled, and would show "Subscribed".

**Current button:**

```
  <x-button>
<a href="subscribes/{{$item->id}}" class="btn btn-dang btn-xs" id="subscribeButton">Subscribe</a>
</x-button>
```

**EDIT:**

So I had an idea, to check if this specific combination of campaign_id and user_id exists within the pivot table, and get a boolean.

**Controller**

```
    public static function button(Request $request)
{
    $campaignUser = User::find($request->user()->id);
    $hasCampaign = $campaignUser->campaigns()->where('id', $request->id)->exists();
    return $hasCampaign;
}
```

I do receive a proper response, either 1 or something else.

Now I am trying to call it from the view (still checking if it would work):

```
    @if(App\Http\Controllers\SubscribeController::button() == 1)
echo "Yes";
@else
echo "No";
@endif
```

The current issue, is that of course, I need to somehow pass the Request $request into the function, though, not sure if it is even possible.

If it would work like that, I would try to adjust my button code by example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="{{ $post->status == 1 ? 0 : 1 }}"/>
@if($post->status == 1)
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribed"/>
@else
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"/>
@endif
```

So the current question, is if I am even doing it correctly, and if so, how to pass the Request into the function?

Comment: I am sorry but we are mostly not going to help you create code, but we will help you with your existing tried code, so did you try anything? what is not working?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have adjusted my post once again, as I have tried using database queries in regards to results. Although, doing it for the first time, so most likely it is incorrect pov of doing this query.